# Tastypie randomly throws ImproperlyConfigured URLConf errors

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I've started messing around with Tastypie and have encountered a problem where a GET request for any object within my db will sometimes return the object successfully, and other times will return a 500 error with a "The included urlconf  doesn't have any patterns in it".

Below I have included the result of two queries via CURL. One returns the object, and the one immediately after that returns the 500 error (I cut the 500 result short)

```
mrichardson@box [16:40] :~$ curl http://localhost:10000/app/app/bbaa8eba-5065-405f-8c65-abfdb05b5a7f/?format=json
 {"code": "", "created": "2013-11-29T22:26:39", "id": "bbaa8eba-5065-405f-8c65-abfdb05b5a7f", "key": ">^GlK;8%UBpB!x8!jC][[cV%6", "modified": "2013-11-29T22:26:39", "name": "", "resource_uri": "/app/app/bbaa8eba-5065-405f-8c65-abfdb05b5a7f/"}

mrichardson@box [16:40] :~$ curl http://localhost:10000/app/app/bbaa8eba-5065-405f-8c65-abfdb05b5a7f/?format=json
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE">
  <title>ImproperlyConfigured at /app/app/bbaa8eba-5065-405f-8c65-abfdb05b5a7f/</title>
```

My URL conf is configured as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from app.resources import app_resource

appres = app_resource()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^app/', include(appres.urls)),
)
```

And app.resources looks like this:

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from app.models import app


class app_resource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = app.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'app'
```

The problem occurs when I'm requesting anything, not just specific objects. For example, if I just wanted to get the app/app list of entities.

```
mrichardson@box [16:56] :~$ curl -X GET -I  http://localhost:10000/app/app/?format=json
HTTP/1.1 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
Date: Sat, 30 Nov 2013 05:56:43 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html

mrichardson@box [16:56] :~$ curl -X GET -I  http://localhost:10000/app/app/?format=json
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 30 Nov 2013 05:56:44 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Vary: Accept
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Cache-Control: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json
```

Can anyone offer me any suggestions on what might be causing this behavior?

Comment: I've just discovered that this is only happening with Apache2. If I use the django built-in web server, I get a 200 response every time?

Comment: Restarting apache fixed it. Found it after a suggestion in this thread: stackoverflow.com/questions/20130675/